# Creating bootable Debian with Rufus: Unsupported image error

Tags: linux, windows, debian, iso-image, rufus

I want to make a bootable Debian flash drive.

Seemed straightforward, something I did before with different distros and specialized tools.

I grabbed the armhf image from here: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/armhf/iso-cd/debian-9.3.0-armhf-netinst.iso

Plugged in the flash drive, formatted it and gave image to Rufus with default settings.

Unfortunately Rufus kept giving me the Unsupported image error. I checked the hash, and it seemed to be ok. So I grabbed the full image from torrent. Only to get the same error.

I tried all the available partition schemes in Rufus, with no success. I even tried a different drive, although I was pretty much sure it is innocent in this.

At this point I am pretty dumbstruck. I can get a different distro, but I don't like the idea of not knowing where is the problem.

Comment: Use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) instead of Rufus.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here in my opinion, to create bootable USB pendrive, is not <s>`debian-9.3.0-armhf-netinst.iso`</s> image, but `debian-9.3.0-armhf-xfce-CD-1.iso`
according to this :

> **What is a netinst image?**
>   The netinst CD here is a small CD image that contains just the core 
>   Debian installer code and a small core set of text-mode programs (known as 
>   "standard" in Debian). To install a desktop or other common software, 
>   you'll also need either an Internet connection or some other Debian 
>   CD/DVD images.

Hope this helps.